# In Laravel, how do you use a "cannot" in a Route::middleware group?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware, laravel-gate

I have my own Laravel gates defined "isAdmin" and "isManager".  The "auth" middleware simply means the user is logged in.  My routes look like this (greatly simplified):

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'can:isAdmin'])->group(
    function () {
        Route::get('/', function() { return response("Admin home"); });
    }
);

Route::middleware(['auth', 'can:isManager'])->group(
    function () {
        Route::get('/', function() { return response("Manager home"); });
    }
);
```

But what do I do for a route for a logged-in user who is neither an admin nor a manager?  I would like to do this:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'cannot:isManager', 'cannot:isAdmin'])->group(
    function () {
        Route::get('/', function() { return response("Who are you, anyway?"); });
    }
);
```

Anybody have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the route to only be accessible for users that aren't either an admin or manage, or can admin's and manager's view that page as well?

Comment: No, admins and managers shouldn't see it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a `cannnot` middleware. You could create a `cannot` middleware but I would recommend just making another gate that checks to see if the user is a "standard" user (or however would be best to describe them).

Answer (score 0):

you can set new rule (gate) as notAdminAndManager in app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php on boot method
here is some example

```
Gate::define('isNotAdminAndManager', function (User $user) {
    return (! in_array($);
});
```